# JSON Gem will not install (Windows)

Tags: ruby, windows, json, rubygems

Every time I try updating or installing the JSON gem I get a build error. These are the results in the output file:

```
c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
generating parser-i386-mingw32.def
compiling parser.c
In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1360,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:6,
                 from parser.rl:1:
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:41: error: redefinition of 'struct timespec'
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:48: error: redefinition of 'struct timezone'
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1
```

I'm starting learning Rails and I wanted to figure this out before I continue.

---

Here's the default Gemfile that was generated:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '~> 0.8.3', :require => false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For building Gems that require native build tools make sure you have the [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) installed. Instructions are provided in the link.

Could you add the results of the `gem install json` or appropriate command please?

Answer (score 0):

If this is just locally, you can always take the easy way out and `gem install json_pure` instead (a 100% Ruby implementation, it's slow but it works)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but this worked for me: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#gems_fails_comspec_autorun

Specifically Scenario B

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /s
```

if you get a 'AUTORUN' response, remove it as follows:

```
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```