# Can't install json gem in Windows

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems, devkit

I tried to install the json gem on Windows. I installed DevKit. I get the following error below. Any suggestions? This question

[JSON Gem will not install (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840804/json-gem-will-not-install-windows)

suggests installing DevKit and also try using json_pure. I did both. The problem is that my bundle install is trying to install json and won't proceed until json is installed. This is a bundle install for a Rails project btw.

```
d:\source\my_project>gem install json -v '1.6.3'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating parser-i386-mingw32.def
compiling parser.c
In file included from parser.rl:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:129:13: warning: 'fbuffer_append_long' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:136:17: warning: 'fbuffer_dup' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:149:14: warning: 'fbuffer_to_s' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:90:13: warning: 'fbuffer_append_str' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
linking shared-object json/ext/parser.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 parser.so C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/json/ext
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/json/ext': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, solved this by doing this:

Using *Ruby version - 2.2.2*

*Gem version - 2.3.0* (if you have the latest gem version install you can downgrade using command - `gem update --system 2.3.0`)

Please note even if you are 64 bit windows system, download and extract 32 bit devkit (*DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe*) from [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

Once extracted, add the path to devkit & mingw\bin to your path variable
Navigate to devkit directory & run below commands

```
ruby dk.rb init

ruby dk.rb install
```

Finally, restart the command prompt & try

```
gem install json
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the version 1.7.7. 
I do not why but it seems that it is compatible with your ruby version.
Do: gem install json -v '1.7.7'

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, i download wrong version of Ruby (32bit), but i using 64bit windows => error occur. 
The first thing you need is check if development kit work correctly.

```
gem install json --platform=ruby
```

if it cant not work , you should follow bellow tutorial to make it work. 
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

And after this, you can install json gem normaly. I think.
Good luck.